# Javascript Date() function not working in Safari (iOS)

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios

I am using Date() function to get current date and compare it to another date.

It's working fine with Android and web but it's not working in iOS .

My code is:

```
function daytogo()
        {
              var status = document.getElementById('dmy_status').getAttribute('value');
            if(status =='C')
            {
                var event_status="Event has been cancelled";
            }
            else if(status =='P')

            {
                var event_status="Event postponed ! Waiting for new date";
            }
            else
            {
                        /*START OF CALCULATING DATE DIFFERENCE*/
                    var oneDay = 24*60*60*1000; // hours*minutes*seconds*milliseconds

                    var a = document.getElementById('dmy_strt').getAttribute('value');
                    var b = document.getElementById('dmy_end').getAttribute('value');
                    //var firstDate = new Date(2008,01,12);
                   // alert(b);
                    //alert(firstDate);
                    var today = new Date();
                    var dd = today.getDate();
                    var mm = today.getMonth()+1; //January is 0!
                    var yyyy = today.getFullYear();

                    if(dd<10) {
                        dd='0'+dd
                    } 

                    if(mm<10) {
                        mm='0'+mm
                    }

                    today = yyyy+','+mm+','+dd;
                    // document.write(today);
                       var firstDate = new Date(a);
                       var secondDate = new Date(today);
                       var enddate=new Date(b);
                       console.log(firstDate);
                       console.log(secondDate);
                    // alert(today);
                    //    var diffDays = Math.abs((firstDate.getTime() - secondDate.getTime())/(oneDay));
                 //    alert(diffDays);
                      if(firstDate > secondDate)
                       {
                                alert("if");
                                var event_status='';
                                var diffDays = Math.abs((firstDate.getTime() - secondDate.getTime())/(oneDay));
                                //alert(diffDays);
                                if(diffDays <=30 )
                                {
                                     event_status=diffDays + " days to go";
                                } 
                                else
                                {
                                    event_status=(diffDays /30);
                                    event_status=(event_status.toString().split(".")[0])+ ' months to go'; ///before
                                    //alert(event_status.toString().split(".")[1]); ///after
                                }
                        }
                        else if(firstDate <= secondDate && enddate >= secondDate)
                        {
                            alert("else if");
                            var event_status='Ongoing';
                        }
                        else
                        {
                             alert("else");
                                var event_status="Event has expired";
                                //document.getElementById("days_to_go").innerHTML = event_status;
                        }
                     //var elements = document.getElementsByClassName('dmy_strt')[0].value;
                    /*END OF THE DATE DIFFERENCE*/ 


                    /*START OF EVENT STATUS */


            }

            document.getElementById("days_to_go").innerHTML = event_status;
```

And date format is - 'YYYY,mm,dd'
and I have tried 'YYYY/mm/dd' format also.

But in case of iOS it's going to else case always (var event_status="Event has expired";).

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 1):

> There are 4 ways of initiating a date:
>
> ```js
> new Date()
> new Date(milliseconds)
> new Date(dateString)
> new Date(year, month, day, hours, minutes, seconds, milliseconds)
> ```

You don't follow any of them. Read [the basics of Date object](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_dates.asp).

Comment: OP's date formats are actually valid as a dateString in Javascript, problem exists within Safari, which returns invalid dates where other browsers will accept the dateStrings as posted