# jQuery new Date() not working in Safari

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, safari

The function below calculates the age based of the given parameters.

```
var now = new Date();
var past = new Date(select_year + "-" + select_month + "-" + select_day); 
var nowYear = now.getFullYear();
var pastYear = past.getFullYear();
var age = nowYear - pastYear;
```

It works perfectly in Chrome.

But when I switch over to Safari, the following line says `Invalid Date`:

`var past = new Date(select_year + "-" + select_month + "-" + select_day);`

I'm assuming it is failing to reconstruct the date.

---

Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Javascript Date() function not working in Safari (iOS)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29652102/javascript-date-function-not-working-in-safari-ios)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For Internet Explorer and Safari, you need to change the format up a bit. I believe that this will work for you:

```
var d = new Date(2011, 01, 07);  
var d = new Date(2011, 01, 07, 11, 05, 00); 
var d = new Date("02/07/2011");  
var d = new Date("02/07/2011 11:05:00");  
var d = new Date(1297076700000); 
var d = new Date("Mon Feb 07 2011 11:05:00 GMT");
```

Found [here](http://biostall.com/javascript-new-date-returning-nan-in-ie-or-invalid-date-in-safari/).

Comment: Is `"mm/dd/yyyy"` supported by Chrome and Firefox then?

Comment: That would be Yes `:)` Thanks.

Comment: @cyanCoding any reason why safari behaves like this if date is coming "2011-01-07"